# Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' to 'NSMutableDictionary'

Tags: swift, nsmutabledictionary

I recently started working with swift. I am using below code to cast string to nsmutabledictionary.

```
print(response);
let responseData = response.data(using: .utf8)!
var json: NSMutableDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as! NSMutableDictionary;
```

The response from server for request is like below.

```
{"token1":"blah.blah.blah","token_type":"smarty","expires_in":1209600,"token2":"blah.blah.blah"}
```

I am stuck here. Please help.

Comment: share some code what you try and where it gives you error.

Comment: Do not use `JSONSerialization` in Swift. Use `Codable` and `JSONDecoder` instead. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50086418/4667835) Q&A. You can also use [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io) to automatically generate the parsing code for you.

Comment: `var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [String: Any]` to get a mutable native swift dictionary

Comment: Thanks @JoakimDanielson it worked. Although I don't get why the approach failed. What is difference between NSMutableDictionary and [String:Any]

Comment: Because `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])` is a `NSDictionary`, not a `NSMutableDictionary`, it's not Mutable, that's why. Using Swift Dictionary is different.

Comment: And to add to that, don't use NS classes like NSDictionary when there is a native Swift equivalent. And we use `var/let` when declaring variables to make them mutable/imutable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no surprise because it's exactly the same behavior as in Objective-C.

In ObjC you cannot cast an immutable type to a mutable. Running this code

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"Foo":@"1"};
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = (NSMutableDictionary *)dict;
[mutableDict setObject:@"2" forKey: @"Bar"];
```

raises an exception

> -[__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

because the type remains immutable. You have to create a new `NSMutableDictionary` instance

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];
```

---

Ironically – I'm still talking about ObjC – in case of `NSJSONSerialization` the famous option `.mutableContainers` comes in. With this option you can create a mutable array / dictionary directly, please note, only in Objective-C.

On the other hand in Swift this option makes no sense anyway because Swift `Dictionary` / `Array` and the `NSMutable...` counterparts are not related to each other, and in Swift you can make a (native) type mutable simply with the `var` keyword.

So write

```
var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData) as! [String:Any]
```

---

**The bottom line is:**

**Don't use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift at all.**

Answer (score 0):

[`jsonObject(with:options:)`](http://jsonObject(with:options:)) returns `Any`, you may try :

```
let response = """
    {"token1":"blah.blah.blah","token_type":"smarty","expires_in":1209600,"token2":"blah.blah.blah"}
"""
let responseData = response.data(using: .utf8)!
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as! [String: Any]
let mutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: json)
```